# Include multiple blocks in one responsive menu?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

It would be really handy to include not just one menu in a responsive dropdown menu, but also the user login block, the main menu etcetera. Is there a way to do that? I have tried several responsive menu modules, but it seems as though I always end up with several different dropdown menus. I only want one (for all).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate Mega menu options.

http://megadrupal.com/blog/7-mega-menu-modules-for-drupal

I've used OM Maximenu before when I wanted a ton of content on the dropdown:

https://www.drupal.org/project/om_maximenu